# How MPI_File_write_at_all can be used to write unequal number of lines into a file from various processor including master node?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to write different number of lines to a file  from various processors. i have done this by using MPI_Gatherv and C-file output function.But I wants to do it by using MPI file I/O. Could  anyone provide the source code for MPI_file_write_at_all in C??

Comment: There's at least one high-quality MPI implementation available in open source for you to inspect.  Use your favourite search engine to find it.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to assume you want an example of code using MPI_File_write_at_all.

```
MPI_File_open()

/* compute amount of data */
/* compute offsets */
/* Here is a good place to use MPI_Exscan */j
MPI_File_write_at_all()
MPI_Close()
```